# How to get back to root Activity from Java Code ? (Android)

Tags: android

Im creating activities as following.

A->B->C->D

When i click a button in D i need to go back to the home screen (which is A).

Can anyone suggest me some code to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you need to go to android home screen? Then it is a different thing.

But if 'A' is the main activity of your application, then you can call activity  'A' with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. This will clear all activity above 'A' and make top of stack.

Comment: can you please tell me how to call it from inside activity D?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity( intent );

Comment: nice you found the answer... :)

Comment: It actually leaves you with D->A since it adds the "clear top" activity underneath the current activity. Not quite what the user wants I believe!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) topic in the dev guide.